# Upload and get image on Tomcat embed server(Heroku Deploy) Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, file-storage

I'm new to Spring(Spring MVC).I have a task to save an image, upload it and save it to the server (embed Tomcat server). I implemented the following code.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    public String upload(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile multipartFile, @ModelAttribute("movie") Movie movie) {
        String filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/avatars/");

        try {
            multipartFile.transferTo(new File(filePath, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        movie.setUrlAvatar(filePath + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

        movieService.createMovie(movie); // Save to DB

        return "redirect: home";
    }
```

And my view

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${movies}">
    <li>
        <a href='<c:url value= "/movie/${item.getId()}"></c:url>'><img
            alt="${item.getUrlAvatar()}" src='<c:url value="${item.getUrlAvatar()}"></c:url>'>
        </a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

I even try `src='<c:url value="file:///${item.getUrlAvatar()}"></c:url>'` and it not working !!!
Where am I wrong when I cannot get the pictures out. Is there any way to get the images out ??

Can you suggest me a way to save images and remove images (I don't want to save to the Database now)?

Thank to all you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem at

```
movie.setUrlAvatar(getBaseURL(request) + "/avatars/" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
```

with

```
// get base URL
    public String getBaseURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
                + request.getContextPath();
    }
```

And I have to do this

```
File dir = new File(rootPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + avatarNewName);
```

Then `multipartFile.transferTo(serverFile);`
I found this at [here](https://ariestania.wordpress.com/2015/12/08/how-to-upload-image-and-display-it-on-spring-mvc/)